# Do exorcists and kegares exist outside Japan?

Tags: twin-star-exorcists

In the anime they mention that the 12 guardians, the 12 most powerful exorcists after the chief exorcist and the Miko are in Japan. As a matter of fact, everything seems to happen in Japan. IIRC, Benio and Rokuro travels through Japan to fight Kegares. So, does anything happen outside Japan regardings Kegares and exorcists?

Do exorcists and kegares exist outside Japan?